# Perl $! returns "Bad file descriptor" at once and "No such file or directory" when run in debug mode (not Perl's debug mode)

Tags: perl

I have this Perl code:

```
foreach my $eachFile (@FileList)
{
    $cmd = "xcopy /I /F /V /Y /R \"$ProjectPath\\$eachFile\" \"$NewPath\\\"";
    print "\n\t$cmd\n";
    my $result = system($cmd);
    die "ERROR: Could not copy from $viewPath to $DLPath: $!" if ($result > 0);
}
```

In this code, I have put lines like: `system("pause") if ($debug)` which pauses the execution when $debug variable is set.

Now, the above xcopy dies as one file is not present. But, the $! prints : "Bad file descriptor" when run normally, and it print : "No such file or directory" when I set the $debug variable.

Any idea why does $! give different message for the two instances?

Comment: *Always* `use strict; use warnings;`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation for [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html).  `$!` is only meaningful if `system` itself fails and returns `-1`.  Otherwise, you have to figure out what the error means on your own by picking apart `$?`.  A sample from the documentation:

```
if ($? == -1) {
    print "failed to execute: $!\n";
}
elsif ($? & 127) {
    printf "child died with signal %d, %s coredump\n",
        ($? & 127),  ($? & 128) ? 'with' : 'without';
}
else {
    printf "child exited with value %d\n", $? >> 8;
}
```

So you shift `$?` right by 8 bits, and that's the error code returned by `xcopy`.  There's a list of `xcopy`s error codes [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true).

That's the way it *should* behave, anyway.  In my testing with this:

```
my $ProjectPath = "c:\\temp";
my @FileList    = qw(aaa.txt asdf bbb.txt empty_dir beans.txt foo.pl);
my $NewPath     = "c:\\temp2";

foreach my $eachFile (@FileList) {
    print "Copying $eachFile\n";
    my $result = system(
        qw(xcopy /I /F /V /Y /R), "$ProjectPath\\$eachFile", "$NewPath\\"
    );

    if ($? == -1) {
        die "failed to execute: $!";
    }
    elsif ($? > 0) {
        my $foo = $? >> 8;
        print "Error code: $foo\n";
        die "no files found to copy"          if $foo == 1;
        die "user pressed ctrl-c during copy" if $foo == 2;
        die "initialization error"            if $foo == 4;
        die "disk write error writing"        if $foo == 5;
        die "unknown error";
    }
}
```

It reports "initialization error" when it finds that there is no `beans.txt` in my temp directory.  I don't know what I'd have to do to make `xcopy` return a `1`.  C'est la vie.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But, why does $! gives different values for different conditions? What makes a difference when I set the $debug variable? It just executes a system("pause")..?
Should I use backticks instead of system and then search it for any errors?

Also, could you elaborate on the sample code you mentioned? It's a bit confusing. For calculating, we do ($? & 127) but while printing "with" or "without", we do ($? & 128)

Comment: If nothing specifically causes an error, `$!`'s value is meaningless -- there's no point in even looking at it.  If you right-shift `$?` with `$foo = $? >> 8`, then `$foo` will be the errorlevel that `xcopy` returns.  So if `$foo == 1`, then no files were found to copy.  You can probably ignore the bit flags on 127 and 128.

Comment: Well, here, there is an error occurring - one file is not found at the specified location while copying. Also, when I run  the program with $debug set, the program pauses at instances where I have written `system("pause")` and then $! does print "No such file or directory". It's just that when not running with the $debug set, I get the other message (which you might be saying as meaningless, if I'm not wrong).

Comment: Okay, *stop looking at `$!` if there isn't actually an error*.  Its value is *meaningless*.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a system command when you can use Perl. Otherwise, why bother with Perl?

There is a file `copy` command in Perl. It's not part of the base commands, but is available via the [File::Copy](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html) module. Don't be confused into thinking that this isn't part of *Standard Perl*, and shouldn't be used. The `File::Copy` module has been around for a long, long time, and is part of every Perl installation you will run into. Learn the various ***standard*** Perl modules, and use them as if they are part of the base Perl because they are.

And, don't be afraid of installing CPAN Perl modules. These modules can extend Perl in wonderful ways (for example, parsing JSON, YAML, and XML files or interacting with the World Wide Web). Remember that the best Perl programmers are darn lazy and won't write code if someone else has already did it for them.

All I had to do to get that `copy` command was to add `use File::Copy;` in the top of my Perl script.

Note that my loop contains three lines:

- I verify the file exists via the `-f` command.
- I tell you what I am doing (You had `/V` there in your `xcopy` command)
- I copy the file.

Also note that I *changed* your variable names. In Perl, the standard is to use underscores and lowercase for variable names. Also, it's now standard to simply say `for` instead of `foreach` which saves you typing four characters.

I use the `use feature qw(say);` pragma which enables the `say` command. I like it much better than `print` since `say` automatically adds the `\n` to the end of the line. This sounds like a tiny thing, but after you forget `\n` a few times, of find situations where putting `\n` changes your output in ways you didn't anticipate, you appreciate the `say` command.

I use another module called `File::Path` which gives me the `make_path` command. This command is an extension of the built in `mkdir` command. However, it makes the directory and all parent directories required to make the directory you want. If you don't need to worry about making the entire path, you can simply use `mkdir` and not include `File::Path`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use File::Copy;
use File::Path qw(make_path);

...

if ( not -d $project_path ) {
    make_path $project_path
            or die qq(Can't create directory "$project_path");
    }
}

for my $file in ( @files ) {
    if not ( -f "$project_path/$file" ) {
         die qq(Can't copy non-existant file "$project_path/$file".);
    }
    say qq(Copying "$project_path/$file" to "$new_path");
    copy "$project_path/$file", $new_path
         or die qq(Can't copy "$file": $!);
}
```

Yes, this doesn't answer your *direct* question. However, I wanted you to know the *Perl way* of doing what you want, so you could become a better Perl programmer.

Comment: Well, that does help in writing better programs, thanks for that! I'll think about those tips, but I guess the File::Copy module does not provide as much functionality as the xcopy function provides - viz., the /I, /V, /F, /Y, /R, etc. (for e.g., File::Copy doesn't overwrite read-only files, whereas xcopy does it with /R switch)

Comment: @ss2025 `File:Copy` does have limits, but there are ways to get around these. You could use [chmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chmod.html) before attempting to copy the file in order to set write permission before doing `copy`. `xcopy` also does recursive copying too. This takes a bit more work and a few more standard modules (`File::Find`, `File::Basename`, `File::Path`, and maybe `File::Spec` to be safe). Or, you can use [File::Copy::Recursive](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Copy::Recursive) which as a bonus **can** be set to overwrite existing files.

Comment: When you use the `system` command to do something on your system, you're making assumptions on your system that may or may not be true. For example, a command may exist on one system that maybe different or operates completely differently than another system (especially between Win32 and Unix). Or that you might be relying on behavior on one version of the command that differs between another (Mac OS X vs. Linux). Or, that someone didn't write a batch or shell script with that name in order to add a security hole.

Answer (score 0):

'\' as a separator might be the issue, the Unix-style is '/'.

Comment: Which '\' are you mentioning about? There are quite some '\' and '/' in that code..!

Comment: Its about path. @ss2025